# No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:tcp

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, h2

an java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/ZadatakDB is thrown when I try to connect to h2 database using a java web application.

I can use H2 console without any issue, and pinging is successfull.

I've also added h2-1.3.176 jar file to Libraries AND to WEB-INF/lib.

Here is my Java method I am using to connect:

```
private static Connection connectToDatabase() throws SQLException,
        IOException {

    String url = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/ZadatakDB";
    String username = "student";
    String pw = "student";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
            username, pw);
    return connection;
}
```

What could I be missing?

I will also add StackTrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/ZadatakDB
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at hr.web.aplikacija.DatabaseUtils.connectToDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:20)
at hr.web.aplikacija.DatabaseUtils.insertForm(DatabaseUtils.java:38)
at hr.web.aplikacije.servlet.KorisnikServlet.doPost(KorisnikServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have a ClassNotFound exception in the stack trace ?

Comment: I don't, I have only SQL exception

Comment: And what happens if you use: Class.forName("org.h2.Driver").newInstance(); in the first line of your method? It should register the required driver in DriverManager.

Comment: When I did as you said, by putting that line of code into try-catch block, it worked. Thank you. I will look up documentation on that to learn what it does.

Comment: You should not need to create a NEW instance. Class.forName("org.h2.Driver") is enough.

Answer (score 8):

The JDBC driver for the H2 database is not in the classpath, or the driver is is unloaded. Use this to load the driver class:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
```

Comment: I inserted the line but instead getting an ClassNotFound execption.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write:

```java
DriverManager driver = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, pw);
driver.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
```